# Displaying a DateInterval in Twig

Tags: date, twig, symfony, dateinterval

I'm trying to display a DateInterval in Twig using the following code:

```
{{ event.endTime.diff(event.startTime)|date("i's''") }}
```

where `event` is an Entity who get 2 DateTime object: `endTime` and `startTime`. With that command I've got this output:

```
i's''
```

Instead of `min'sec''` like `08'15''`

It is said in the [date doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/date.html) that

> The date filter accepts [...] DateInterval instances

This work to display min and sec from a date object.

Note that doing: `{{ (event.endTime.diff(event.startTime))|date("i's''") }}` doesn't change anything

I also tried `{{ date(event.endTime.diff(event.startTime))|date("i's''") }}` but this lead to an exception `Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string`

I've also seen `time_diff` from [Twig Extensions](http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/date.html) but this return a string (`in` or `ago`) instead of a Date object, then I can't display it as I want.

Let me know if you need more informations. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `(new \DateTime('tomorrow'))->diff(new \DateTime('now'))->format("i's''")` also gives `"i's''"`, so I'd say this is not a *twig-thing*. From [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php): *"The following characters are recognized in the format parameter string. Each format character must be prefixed by a percent sign (%)."*

Comment: Thank you very much, In fact I had to add `%` before `i` and `s`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Yoshi said:

> `(new \DateTime('tomorrow'))->diff(new \DateTime('now'))->format("i's''")` also gives `"i's''"`, so I'd say this is not a twig-thing. From the manual:
>
> "The following characters are recognized in the format parameter
>   string. Each format character must be prefixed by a percent sign (%)."

So to fix my proble I just had to do:

```
{{ event.endTime.diff(event.startTime)|date("%i'%s''") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

When putting in the method **format** the parameters **'i'** and **'s'** in lowercase, when the value to be displayed is less than 10, put a single digit.

Example if you need to display the time of 5 minutes and 2 seconds by showing a leading zero (05:02). You have to capitalize the parameters, it would be like this:

`{{ event.endTime.diff(event.startTime)|date("%I:%S") }}`

The allowed parameters can be found in: [DateInterval format](https://www.php.net/DateInterval.format)